# Modular invertibility of a primitive matrix

Tags: matrices, modular-arithmetic

> **Question.** 
>   If a matrix $A$ has a primitive characteristic polynomial modulo $p$, how to prove it is invertable modulo $p$.

Due to my prior [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1424394/255648) I know that if a matrix is invertable modulo a prime number $p$, it will be invertable mod $p^a\,,a\in\mathbb{N}$. Now I'm trying to find out what matrices are modular invertable. It seems that the above statement is true.

Comment: Let $f$ be its characteristic polynomial modulo $p$. Then the determinant of $A$ modulo $p$ is $f(0) \neq 0$ so it is invertible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a square matrix $A$ over the integers, compute $\det(A)$.  If $\det(A)=0$, then $A$ will not be invertible mod p for any prime $p$.  However, if $\det(A)=n$, then $A$ will be invertible mod p for every prime $p$ that does NOT divide $n$.

Since the determinant of $A$ is (up to a sign) the constant term of the characteristic polynomial, the condition we care about is not primativity, but just whether zero is a root.  However, since primitive polynomials are irreducible, zero cannot be a root unless it is the only root, in which case $A$ would have been the $1\times 1$ zero matrix, which does not have an inverse.

Comment: Thank you for answering. Could you please add why determinant of A is the constant term of the characteristic polynomial?

Comment: @SMA.D The constant term is what you get when you evaluate at 0. What is the definition of the characteristic polynomial? What do you get when you plug in 0?

Comment: Got it, thank you. $P_A(t)=\textrm{det}(tI-A)$